# Using foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am new to foreign key, but I understand the concept very well.

I have found lot of documentation on how to create / delete them but not how to use them. My schema is as follows.

Stock table:

```
PartID | Model | Type | Vendor
------------------------------
1      | DDr2  | RAM  | shop1
2      | DDr3  | RAM  | shop1
3      | WD1   | HDD  | shop2
4      | WD2   | HDD  | shop2
```

Then product Table

```
ProdID | Name | PartID1 | PartID2 ...
1      | PC1  | 1       | 2
2      | PC1  | 3       | 4
```

How do I use `select` to get

```
| PC1 | DDr2 | DDR3 |
| PC1 | WD1  | WD2  |
```

with `PartID2` and `PartID3` foreign key linked to `PartID` primary key?

Comment: can you post your sql for the table definitions?

Comment: how many parts (partId1, partID2,...) are there ? wouldnt you be better with a many-to-many relation table instead of multiple part columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of Foreign Keys is to link the IDs in one table to the lisk of unique IDs in another. In your example, you have unique parts with unique IDs and Products that can use those parts, so in your product table, you could have multiple part IDs being used in multiple rows.

Foreign Keys are used to keep referential integrity in your database, you can use joins to get the Data you want:

```
SELECT A.NAME,
       B.Model,
       C.Model
FROM PRODUCTS A
       INNER JOIN PARTS B ON B.PARTID1 = A.PARTID
       INNER JOIN PARTS C ON C.PARTID1 = A.PARTID
WHERE A.PRODID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you could do

```
 select p.name, a.model as part1, b.model as part2, c.model as part3 
   from product p, stock a, stock b, stock c 
   where p.partid1 = a.partid and p.partid2 = b.partid and p.partid3 = c.partid
```

The longer answer is that this isn't really a good table design for what you're trying to do. It assumes that you always have a fixed number of parts for any item (or at least no more than some fixed number). A better design would be:

```
Part Table:
partID | model | type | vendor

Product Table:
productID | name

Product_Parts Table:
productID | partID
```

where productID in Product_parts is a foreign key into Product and partID is a foreign key into the Part table.

Comment: This is good advice, it's always best to plan ahead. If you, for whatever reason, add more parts in future then following the suggested schema will prevent you needing to rewrite your SQL queries.

Comment: Yes i would agree but here partID2 is an alternative to PartID1 and each part line in product table is one item in the part list. The product product part list are then done by WHERE product.name = 'pc1"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s1.Name, p1.Model, p2.Model FROM stock st 
    INNER JOIN product p1
       ON st.PartID1 = p1.PartID1
          INNER JOIN product p2
             ON st.PartID2 = p2.PartID1
```

Take one JOIN at the time first join stock and parts table
then again join result of this join to parts table.

SQL parser will use parts table as two separate tables an so you can have two results from same tabe in single row.

Answer (score 0):

you can join in a table more than once in the same sql statement.  in this case, you need to join your stock table twice, once to get the name of each part in your product.

```
SELECT pr.ProdID, s1.Model, s2.Model
FROM Product pr, Stock s1, Stock s2
WHERE pr.PartID1 = s1.PartID
AND pr.PartID2 = s2.PartID
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` means that the product will still be returned event if the `Part1ID` or `Part2ID` values are set to NULL.

```
SELECT          P.Name,
                S1.Model,
                S2.Model
FROM            Product P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Stock S1 ON P.PartID1 = S1.PartID
INNER JOIN      Stock S2 ON P.PartID2 = S2.PartID
```

Comment: yes that work fine with 2 outer: SELECT     P.Name, P.PartType, S1.Model AS exp1, S2.Model AS Exp2
FROM         Product AS P LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Parts AS S1 ON P.PartID1 = S1.PartID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Parts AS S2 ON P.PartID2 = S2.PartID
WHERE     (P.Name = 'p1')